# Python search and print values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the the file output.

```
vNIC Template:
Name: vNIC-120-A
Type: Updating Template
Fabric ID: A B

Ethernet Interface:
    Name: 2-native
    Dynamic MAC Addr: Derived
    Default Network: Yes
    State: progress

    Name: nfs
    Dynamic MAC Addr: Derived
    Default Network: No

    Name: vmotion
    Dynamic MAC Addr: Derived
    Default Network: No
```

How do i verify Name: 2-native name 2-native exits or not.

I can use below code whether it is exist are not:

```
Counting the "string" occurrence in a file
def count_string_occurrence():
   string = "2-native"
   f = open("search.txt")
   contents = f.read()
   f.close()
   print "Number of '" + string + "' in file", contents.count("2-native")
```

in my case  i searched and found 2-Native keyword.
I want to print state value and Dynamic Mac Addr value of the 2-native. Below is the reference

```
    Name: 2-native
    Dynamic MAC Addr: Derived
    Default Network: Yes
    State: progress
```

like if i search  "vNIC Template"
I want to print type value and Fabric value.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use something like:

```
import re
keyword = re.escape("2-native")
result = re.findall(r"Name: {}.*?Addr: ([\w]+).*?State: (.*?)$".format(keyword), contents, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    mac_addr = result[0][0]
    state = result[0][1]
    print(mac_addr, state)
    # Derived progress
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/N8bQBU)

Comment: You are one with the regex.  Great answer.

Comment: Appreciated @Chris!